# Error in Python: TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Tags: python

I am making the number guessing game and i am not sure how to

> TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

```
import random

Randomnumber= random.randint(-10,10)

while -10 < Randomnumber < 10:

    print("Guess the number")
    answer= input("What do you think the number is? ")
    print(answer)
    if Randomnumber == answer:
        print("Correct!")
    elif answer < Randomnumber:
        print("Your answer is smaller than the actual value")
    else:
        print("Your answer is bigger than the actual value")
```

Comment: You need to convert the return value from `input` to an `int`. At present it's a string. Just do `answer= int(input("What do you think the number is? "))`. However also consider if you want to handle the exception if the user types in something that cannot be converted to an integer e.g. `abc`.

Comment: "i am not sure how to" - how to what? Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random

Randomnumber= random.randint(-10,10)

while -10 <= Randomnumber <= 10:

    print("Guess the number")
    answer= input("What do you think the number is? ")
    print(answer)
    if Randomnumber == answer:
        print("Correct!")
        break
    elif answer < Randomnumber:
        print("Your answer is smaller than the actual value")
    else:
        print("Your answer is bigger than the actual value")
```

Also do not enter item in single quotes once input method asks you for input.
You can just type in number and press enter. If you enter number in single or double quotes, it's type will cahnge from number to string and comparison will fail.